# How to grab a href from a specific URL by class?

Tags: html, excel, vba, class, screen-scraping

I need Excel VBA code which triggers when a username is entered into a specific cell within a spreadsheet. This then navigates to the Web page which in this instance is a work directory. It then finds the div class "panel bg-brick-red managed-by"> and returns the href associated with that class as a string.

I then wish to extract from that string a specific part of the href  and paste it into a cell within the spreadsheet.

So you type a username into a specific cell in your spreadsheet to trigger the sub, it navigates to the url of our internal directory to find the person and then grabs from that page their line manager's pay number from the href by stripping that pay number from the href and then pastes the result into a nominated result cell within Excel.

Comment: Lots of q&a on here scraping the web - some even have code you can copy and edit.

Comment: Yeah i've searched but can't see anything like i've actually described hence asking a new question and not just grabbing from another code as i normally would.

Answer (score 0):

A flexible way to extract something from a string is with a Regular Expression pattern match. Add a reference to Microsoft Internet Controls.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExtractFromURL()

    Dim IE As Object, URL As String
    Dim links As Object, link As Object
    Dim href As String, PayNo As String
    
    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    IE.Visible = True
    
    URL = "http://some/web/page"
    IE.navigate URL
    
    Do Until IE.readyState >= 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    ' find element
    Set links = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("panel bg-brick-red managed-by")
    Set link = links(0).getElementsByTagName("a")
    href = link(0).href
    
    ' build regex to pattern match PayNp
    Dim regex As Object, m As Object 'match
    Set regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With regex
       .Global = False
       .MultiLine = False
       .IgnoreCase = True
       .Pattern = "(\d{5,6})" 'a number with 5 to 6 digits
    End With
    
    ' extract number
    If regex.test(href) Then
         Set m = regex.Execute(href) ' match
         PayNo = m(0)
         MsgBox PayNo & " extracted from " & href
    Else
         MsgBox "No number in " & href
    End If
    IE.Quit
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi had to change internet explorermedium to just normal internet explorer to stop an error and changed the pay regex to include a character followed by 6 numbers and changed the result from msg box to go into the desired cell and i am very happy thank you very much

Comment: How do i search for a p tag inside a class instead of a href?  like within a class there are a few lines of different text separated by <p> <\p> i want to search them as well if possible?

Comment: @DaveyBoi_Uk did you try `links(0).getElementsByTagName("p")` ?

Comment: yeah but when I try to retrieve from the Link object it says object doesn't allow it.  I want to grab the text and put it into a string

Comment: Set links = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("profile-data")
    Set link = links(0).getelementsbyTagName("p")
    Pline = link.innertext

Comment: It's ok i've sorted it

Comment: Hi CDP, do you know how i would via VBA search whether a user is on an outlook distribution list and if they are return that TEAM.

so for example.  check usernames outlook member of list and if they're member of Team D Users return Team D

Comment: No worries thanks anyway your other suggestions when modified to my needs worked a treat thank you very much

Comment: i've managed to find an excel worksheet that holds the teams.  What would i use to search for a pay number in that workbook without the other workbook being visible on the screen, locate what row that pay number is in and then set a variable string as the contents of the 5th collumn in the same row that it has found the pay number in?

Comment: @Davey post that as a new question